# Automator passing different variables to a shell script

Tags: shell, automator

I try to use automator for renaming multiple files

I got this far:

[image: Automator screenshot]

the first variable must be inside the Exiftool command line

in this case I selected 2 files, but that could be 1 or 100 files

how do I make this happen? is it possible to start from array key 1 instead of array key 0 for the filenames?

Comment: If you are asking how to shift the arguments, you can use `shift`, but note that the names and paths should be quoted or characters special to the shell (such as space) escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to store `$1` in a variable, then use `shift` to remove it from the argument list, and then use `"$@"` to get all of the remaining arguments (i.e. the original `"$2" "$3" "$4" ...`) Something like this:

```
RenameTo="$1"
shift
echo "New name: $RenameTo"
echo "files:" "$@"
```

I'm not sure exactly  what you're trying to to with `exiftool`, so I won't try to give that full command.

Note that the double-quotes aren't required in zsh, but they make this portable to POSIX-compliant shells. Also, `echo` isn't a very good way to see what a command would do, because it looses the distinction between spaces *within* an argument (e.g. spaces in the new name, or within a filename) and spaces *between* arguments (e.g. between the filenamess in a list of them).

Comment: Ahh I never new the shift command, that one works, thank you so much.
Next step is using the exif tool, but this part works